# How do I uninstall google assistant from raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk

I have a question regarding how to uninstall google assistant on the raspberry pi 3. The files are scattered over the place so deleting is not an option. Is there any command to uninstall google assistant on the raspberry pi? I am using the google assistant SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to run `pip uninstall google-assistant-sdk` to remove the libraries downloaded. There may be a few config files as well located in `~/.config/google-assistant-*` that you can remove.